# QBO3 Workflow Dependencies

Tags: workflow, qbo3

I have a QBO3 workflow using compound dependencies:

- Step A
- Step B
- Step C
- Step D: depends on (Step A or Step B) and (Step C)
- Step E: depends on (Step A) or (Step B and Step C)

QBO3 appears to support my dependency requirement for Step D, but not for Step E.

Can QBO3 be configured to support the dependencies of Step E?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, QBO3 supports `(Step A) or (Step B and Step C)`, but you need to create an extra workflow step to configure it:

- Step A
- Step B
- Step C
- Step D: depends on (Step A or Step B) and (Step C)
- **Step X**: depends on (Step B and Step C)
- Step E: depends on (Step A) or (Step X)

Step X can be an `If/Then` step that evaluates to true (always). It simply won't be created until both Step B and Step C are created.

---

QBO3 dependencies implement and and or statements via a `GroupNumber` column. When evaluating whether or not a step's dependencies have been met, the SQL requires at least 1 dependency for each GroupNumber to have been met.

`(Step A or Step B) and (Step C)`

is configured as:

- Step A.GroupNumber = 0
- Step B.GroupNumber = 0
- Step C.GroupNumber = 1

`(Step A) or (Step B and Step C)`

might be configured as:

- Step A.GroupNumber = 0
- Step B.GroupNumber = 1
- Step C.GroupNumber = 1

but this executes as:

`(Step A) and (Step B or Step C)`

The solution above using an extra step is evaluated as:

- Step X: depends on (Step B and Step C)

  - Step B.GroupNumber = 0
  - Step C.GroupNumber = 1
- Step E: depends on (Step A) or (Step X)

  - Step A.GroupNumber = 0
  - Step X.GroupNumber = 0